# Laravel and Vue Register Data to the Database

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vue-component

I am making a project shall I say, writing a book. The user can create a book and in the first page, he/she will put the Title of the Book, the description also the book cover and I used Vue Components to do it and so far it's working.

How can I make a second page that when the user clicks NEXT Button, the user can start writing the content of the book and when he/she clicks save, it will save to the book that he/she currently working?

***Note:*** On the first page, when the user clicks NEXT Button it will save to the DB which I already finished it and works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the database ID in a session variable then use it as a hidden element(id) to the second page. Load the record and modify the second page, then save it. The step variable indicates how many times they clicked next.

For example,

```
if($request->session()->has('id') && $step >1)
$id = $request->input('id');
$request->session()->put('id',$id);

$book = \App\Book::firstOrNew('id'=> $id)
```

Please note this is not complete code comment if more is necessary.

Comment: thank you for your response. I will try to this and put green check if I got it

Comment: this will help me to guide in the right way. But since I am still studying Laravel, I need to study more to understand the code you shared. Thanks. Will get back to this and put green check soon.

Comment: Actualy you toled that  have already done in the statement the user clicks NEXT Button it will save to the DB which I already finished it and works perfectly.So what you need can tell clearly and when one help you try to smooth at the helper Thanks